# In a CLI application, is it possible to replace `python main.py` with a custom command using Typer?

Tags: python, command-line-interface, typer

A CLI application with python using Typer is executed via `$ python main.py` (my filename is `main.py`). Here is a simplified version of the code:

```py
import typer

app = typer.Typer()

@app.command()
def hello(name: str, age: int, display_age: bool = True):
    print(f"hello {name}",style="bold")

    if display_iq:
       print(f"your age is {age}")

@app.command()
def goodby():
    print("Goodby")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app()
```

To call the method `hello` you use for example `$ python main.py hello Jonh 25`. Where `John` and `25` are the arguments.
However I would like to call the CLI via a custom command, using something like `$ csc hello Jonh 25`.

Is it possible? If so, how can I do it?

**Update**

I found this code to setup the cli application:

```py
from setuptools import find_packages, setup

setup(
    name='main',
    version='0.0.0',
    packages=find_packages(),
    install_requires=[
        'typer'
    ],
    entry_points='''
    [console_scripts]
    csc=main:main
    '''
)
```

I've put this code in a file `setup.py` and executed with `pip install -e .`
It installs the package so when I call `pip list` my cli appears in the list of installed packages:

`main       0.0.0   c:\projects\cli`.

Also a folder is created with the name `main.egg-info`, with several text files inside. However it returns the next error:

```
 ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
     command: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\projects\\cli\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\projects\\cli\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps
    Complete output (16 lines):
    running develop
    running egg_info
    creating main.egg-info
    writing main.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to main.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing entry points to main.egg-info\entry_points.txt
    writing requirements to main.egg-info\requires.txt
    writing top-level names to main.egg-info\top_level.txt
    writing manifest file 'main.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    reading manifest file 'main.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'main.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    running build_ext
    Creating c:\python39\lib\site-packages\main.egg-link (link to .)
    main 0.0.0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
    Installing csc-script.py script to c:\python39\Scripts
    error: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'c:\\python39\\Scripts\\csc-script.py'
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1: 'c:\python39\python.exe' -c 'import io, os, sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'c:\\projects\\cli\\setup.py'"'"'; __file__='"'"'c:\\projects\\cli\\setup.py'"'"';f = getattr(tokenize, '"'"'open'"'"', open)(__file__) if os.path.exists(__file__) 
else io.StringIO('"'"'from setuptools import setup; setup()'"'"');code = f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"', '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, '"'"'exec'"'"'))' develop --no-deps Check the logs for full command output.
```

The command `csc` is therefore not working. My Python version is 3.9.6.
Any clue?

Answer (score 1):

Rename `main.py` to `csc` and add the following as the first line:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
```

Make the file executable and put it in a directory in your `$PATH`.

Comment: thanks, It may work. However I also would like to know some way to do an automatic install. (In order to be possible to publish as pip package). I updated the question with a code I found.

Comment: There are tools to turn a Python script into a binary executable.